# Implementing Search functionality on a datagrid column in C# windows appl

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a windows application using .net 2.0. The UI appl has a datagrid and the data will be populated from the XML file.
The data grid has more than 500 rows. Sorting functionality has implemented. but customer still wants a find option or a search functionality on one of the columns with a text box where user is going to enter first 3 letters and it has to search in the grid and has to show the related rows that starts with the give search criteria.

Any suggestions pls how to implement this....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter option in the BindingSource object.

```
private BindingSource dashBoardBindingSource = new BindingSource();

dashBoardBindingSource.DataSource=<<data source items>>;
dashBoardBindingSource.Filter="Column Name=textbox.text";
datagrid.DataSource = dashBoardBindingSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store off your full collection of data, and then when the filter needs to be performed, create the filtered collection and bind the filtered collection to the grid.  Just wire up appropriate text changed events to your filter box, calling FilterGridData.  It works nicely when filtering via multi-column as well.  Oh, and you don't have to use BindingList here.  Use whatever data source you want to bind to the grid - the core of this is just "create the filtered collection by filtering with LINQ."

```
    BindingList<Foo> _allFoos;

    private void LoadData(IEnumerable<Foo> dataToDisplayInGrid)
    {
        this._allFoos = new BindingList<Foo>(dataToDisplayInGrid.ToList());
        this.FilterGridData(string.Empty);
    }

    private void FilterGridData(string filterText)
    {
        BindingList<Foo> filteredList = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText))
        {
            string lowerCaseFilterText = filterText.ToLower();
            IList<Foo> filteredItems = this._allFoos.Where(x => (x.Name ?? string.Empty).ToLower().Contains(lowerCaseFilterText)).ToList();
            filteredList = new BindingList<Foo>(filteredItems);
        }
        else
        {
            filteredList = new BindingList<Foo>(this._allFoos);
        }

        dataGrid.DataSource = filteredList;
    }
```